# How to reload data from List<Models> to ListView?

Tags: android

I have problem when I try to refresh `ListView` with new data.
Every 1 minute I receive data from server, unpack the data to a POJO class, put it in a `List` and I want to show it in a `listView` but I don't get the new data on the screen.

```
// this code I am calling on every 1 minute to ser new data to list
personList.setAdapter(new PersonListAdapter(MainActivity.this, personData));
((PersonListAdapter) personList.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
```

`personData` is a `List<Person>()`. `Person` is a simple POJO class:

```
public class Person {
    public String name;
    public String age;
}
```

`person` data has size of 50 but the list doesn't show. (When I load it the size is 0, after 1 minute  is 50, after 2 minutes size is 60 and so on, but list stays always empty).
How to reload data from `List<Models>` to `ListView`?

Comment: are you calling `personList.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged()` when you get the new data?

Comment: @tyczj I am always set new Adapter to list and then call notifyDataSetChanged

Comment: show code where you get data from server and when you call it to update the list

Comment: Let's see the code for the adapter. If you never see any entries, then there might be something wrong with your getView() method there.

Answer (score 2):

Dont create a new adapter everytime just create it once

Have your list classwide

```
public List<PersonData> personData;
```

then create your adapter once

```
ArrayAdapter personAdapter = new PersonListAdapter(...);
```

then anytime you need to update your list use the `personData` and then call

```
personAdapter.notifyDatasetChanged();
```

to update

Answer (score 0):

Call  [notifyDataSetChanged()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged%28%29) on your `Adapter`. :

```
personList.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
```